# Problem trying to replace javascript alert() for toast implementation?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Hello all and thanks for reading!

I'm new to SF and I'm not finding a good way to replace the alert()'s I'm using to comunicate with the user.

I'm editing the question based on the answer I recieved.

I replaced the alert() I had in the code for this

```
                   component.find('notifLib').showToast({
                       "title": "Error!",
                       "message": "Please enter a valid ID."
                   });
```

and added this line in the StarWarsForm.cmp

```
<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
```

but when I preview the component and try to see the toast I get this error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in
> $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
> Callback failed:
> apex://StarWarsFormController/ACTION$getCalloutResponse Failing
> descriptor: {markup://lightning:notificationsLibrary}

instead of seeing the toast ...

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

**StarWarsForm.cmp**

```
<!--Search Box -->
<div class="slds-size_3-of-8 slds-align_absolute-center">
    <lightning:input type="search" 
                     label="Enter character ID" 
                     aura:id="characterID" />
    
    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
    
    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" 
                      variant="brand" 
                      type="button" 
                      name="calloutButton" 
                      label="Search" 
                      onclick="{!c.APICallout}" />
</div>
```

**StarWarsController.js**

```
APICallout : function(component, event, helper) {
    let id = component.find("characterID").get("v.value");
    helper.getResponse(component, id);
},
```

**StarWarsFormHelper.js**

```
     getResponse : function(component, id){
        let action = component.get("c.getCalloutResponse");
        
        action.setParams({
            "url": 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/'+id+'/'
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            
        let state = response.getState();
            
        if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
            if(response.getReturnValue() != null){
                component.set("v.response", response.getReturnValue());
                
                //Fill the attributes
                let name = component.get("v.response")['name'];
                let planet = component.get("v.response")['homeworld'];
                let gender = component.get("v.response")['gender'];
                let height = component.get("v.response")['height'];
                let hair_color = component.get("v.response")['hair_color'];
                let eyes_color = component.get("v.response")['eye_color'];
                let url = component.get("v.response")['url'];

                //Set the attribute to the attribute on component.
                component.set("v.CharacterName", name);
                component.set("v.CharacterHairColor", hair_color);
                component.set("v.CharacterEyesColor", eyes_color);
                component.set("v.CharacterPlanet", planet);
                component.set("v.CharacterHeight", height);
                component.set("v.CharacterGender", gender);
                component.set("v.CharacterUrl", url);
                
                // Enable Create Character button on successful callout 
                let button = component.find("createButton");
                button.set('v.disabled', false);

            } else{
                    //Set the attribute to the attribute on component.
                    component.set("v.CharacterName", '');
                    component.set("v.CharacterHairColor", '');
                    component.set("v.CharacterEyesColor", '');
                    component.set("v.CharacterPlanet", '');
                    component.set("v.CharacterHeight", '');
                    component.set("v.CharacterGender", '');
                    component.set("v.CharacterUrl", '');
                    
                    // Disable Create Character button on unsuccessful callout 
                    let button = component.find("createButton");
                    button.set('v.disabled', true);

                // replaced ---> alert('Please enter a valid ID');
                component.find('notifLib').showToast({
                       "title": "Error!",
                       "message": "Please enter a valid ID."
               });
         }  
            }else if(state === "ERROR"){
                let errors = response.getError();
                if(errors){
                    if(errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                }else{
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                } 
           }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

it's weird because it works fine with the `alert()` but not with the toast I'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toast in [Notifications Library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation)

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
    <lightning:button name="toast" label="Show Toast" onclick="{!c.handleShowToast}"/>
</aura:component>
```

constroller JS:

```
({
    handleShowToast : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find('notifLib').showToast({
            "title": "Success!",
            "message": "The record has been updated successfully."
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the help ! I've edited the question because I don't have a button in my case and I've tried this way but not working ... can't see why !

Answer (score 0):

Some events only work under **One.app container**. Please check if you're using in one.app container(if you're using it on VF page, it won't work directly).

It'll not work with Custom App, pls try this on record page for immediate testing.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer ! I'm not using VF, this is Aura components. The StarWarsForm.cmp component is inside a .app application which is the unique container of it

Comment: 2 possiblities are there::: 1-- setParams undefined check why its undefined ||| 2nd you can try this - I'd recommend try this in plain controller so that you'll get to know if its a toast issue or your code issue. - 
var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "title": "Success!",
        "message": "The record has been updated successfully."
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
}

Comment: I'm getting the problem only when I change that line ... the alert() for the new toast code ... before, with the alert() the code is working fine ... I can't figure out what's wrong with the new code I'm adding and I can't see anything that breaks the logic

Comment: Could it be something that I'm implementing in the component  ?? implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"

Comment: Ideally it should not be interface part. Pls see your app is using - extends="force:slds" 
and try to remove your all code just see with toast code, if it is working means it is not a toast error. Rest you can debug your code line by line.

Comment: I've created a new single component and add that one to the .app and it's still not working. This component consists only of the code I was provided in the first answer, nothing else ... the app is indeed extending force:slds ... any idea ?

Comment: It's not working with App, pls try on record page.